# Is there a way to list all the ID's of the Discord servers the bot is in?

Tags: javascript, discord

I know you can list all the names of the Discord servers the bot is in using client.guilds.array() but is there a way to list all the ID's of the servers the bot is in?

I've tried many ways and I just can't figure it out.

I've tried "client.guilds.id", "client.guilds.array().id" and many other things I could think of but got no luck.

`message.channel.send(client.guilds.id)`
Something along the lines of this.

The errors I get trying this is: `DiscordAPIError: Cannot send an empty message`

Comment: I think you should add the `discord`tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work - `message.channel.send(client.guilds.map(g => g.id).join("\n"))`